# Cant add api resource to AWS Amplify project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

So I have ran the following commands to initialize my amplify project:

```
amplify configure
amplify init
```

Then i run `amplify add api`.

when I select "REST" api, it says "There was an error adding the API resource" Running `amplify status` confirms that nothing was added. However, when I try to add the "GraphQL" api, it gives me the same error message, but running `amplify status` indicates that it was actually added successfully.

i want to add REST api to my amplify app. Not sure what the issue is. I have tried updating amplify cli and reinitializing my project multiple times. thanks in advance.

Comment: problem occurs with gitbash, and using the command line reolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing a similar error in the step:
Try opening with system-default editor instead?

The error is:

[image]

There are 2 options that helped me

- On this step select **No**
- Install **xdg-utils**: sudo yum -y install xdg-utils (I am using EC2 linux 2 instance)

Try these options and let's see if it helps you.